# Sun JDK /Open JDK on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, java, jstack

Is any version of Sun JDK or Open JDK available to be installed on cygwin.

Reason I am looking for this option is: There are many tools (e.g. jStack, jMap) which are available in unix versions of JDK but not for windows version. I need to exploit the same on my windows machine using Cygwin if possible.

Comment: Have you considered dual booting?

Comment: The standard Sun/Oracle JDK runs jstack and jmap under cygwin/bash (Though they are not cygwin apps)

Comment: dual boot or use VirtualBox to use a linux os

Comment: @Freddie Thanks, but I was looking an option where I can use Cygwin to do the job!

Comment: How would this be more better than having a DOS box next door to run them from? Or a copy of VirtualVM?

Comment: there are many tools/options available for Unix based JVMs as compare to Windows based JVMs!

Comment: you need to bootstrap it first. it might take a while but your best bet is to begin with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikes it is outdated, but this should be enough for a bootstrap https://issues.guix.gnu.org/26966

Answer (score 2):

The Windows version should work alright, and is now available pre-built
https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds/downloads

Comment: It works alright, but not perfectly. For example, it won't understand Cygwin-format absolute filenames.

Comment: This is a 2 years old answer. Check may be Azul and RedHat OpenJDK distros for Windows?

Comment: Neither of them offer Cygwin builds. It may be a two year old answer, but it seems to still be the best one (although Windows OpenJDK builds are now available from Oracle themselves). Especially since GCJ has now been abandoned and was never released for Cygwin 64-bit anyway.

Comment: Yeah. I gave up on using Cygwin entirely. I now run Linux as my primary OS desktop, Windows in a VM when needed. And only Windows-built on Windows unless absolutely necessary as a last resort for a few non-portable POSIX-only utilities where the Cygwin DLL would be needed to compile and run. I would never use an OpenJDK built on Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

The [OpenJDK site](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html#cygwin) has build / compile instructions for a Cygwin environment:

I have however not encountered pre-built binaries that are intended to run on CygWin - yet.

Comment: Those instructions use Cygwin tools and Visual Studio to build the Windows version of the JDK, but not a Cygwin version that would use the Unix compatibility layer provided by Cygwin.